# Python GEKKO Using Manipulation Variables

Tags: python, gekko

Using Python GEKKO with IPOPT for Poliastro/Astropy, I have the following:

```
# Manipulating variables and initial guesses
launch = m.MV(value = 2460159.5, lb = 2460159.5, ub = 2460525.5)
launch.STATUS = 1
flyby = m.MV(value = 2460424.5, lb = 2460342.5, ub = 2460525.5)
flyby.STATUS = 1
arrival = m.MV(value = 2460694.5, lb = 2460480.5, ub = 2460845.5)
arrival. STATUS = 1
```

In my calculations, I have:

```
# Dates
date_launchE = Time(launch, format="jd", scale="utc").tdb
date_flyby = Time(flyby, format="jd", scale="utc").tdb # Mars
date_arrivalE = Time(arrival, format="jd", scale="utc").tdb
```

However, I am getting an error on 'launch', telling me:

> ValueError: Input values did not match the format class jd: TypeError:
> for jd class, input should be doubles, string, or Decimal, and second
> values are only allowed for doubles.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can access the value of 'launch' (i.e., 2460159.5) to convert the time format as needed for the subsequent code?

I have tried to look into 'launch', with a print() command, but it just returns 'p1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.value[0]` to access the numerical quantity of a Gekko variable. It is available only symbolically until after a successful `m.solve()`.

```py
# Dates
date_launchE = Time(launch.value[0], format="jd", scale="utc").tdb
date_flyby = Time(flyby.value[0], format="jd", scale="utc").tdb # Mars
date_arrivalE = Time(arrival.value[0], format="jd", scale="utc").tdb
```

If `.value[0]` is used to define the model then it uses only the initialized value that is default `0`. Gekko requires the equations to be created with specialized functions that are defined in the package to create a symbolic representation. This is compiled into byte-code for efficient evaluation of the equations and the automatic differentiation to obtain sparse gradients. Calls to black-box models are not currently allowed to define Gekko equations. Black-box models can be approximated with [cspline](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ObjectCspline) (1D), [bspline](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ObjectBspline) (2D), or [machine learning methods](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ml.html) (multi-dimensional) as surrogate models.